# Приложение не запускается на другом компьютере, проблема с DLL. C# / Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2015

Привет ребят, нужна ваша помощь. 
Не так давно самостоятельно изучаю этот прекрасный язык (C#), и собираю камни.

Проблема заключается в том, что приложение отказывается запускаться на другом компьютере.
Причина в стороннем DLL файле, который я использую.

Подключил его с помощью ссылки, в проекте все работает отлично, у меня запускается и работает корректно. Но когда пытаюсь запустить на другом компе, программа шлёт меня, со словами: "Прекращена работа программы", Имя события проблемы: CLR20r3. Хотя файл DLL лежит вместе с exe-шником.

Помогите в решении данной проблемы!

Заранее благодарен!)

[image: Подключил DLL как ссылку]
[image: Программа работает корректно при дебагинге]

Comment: Вполне может быть что этому DLL-файлу нужно что-то еще, чего на другой машине нет.

Comment: А ты точно на другой комп прогу вместе с dll копируешь?

Comment: Посмотрите зависимости той dll на которую ссылаетесь.

Comment: Qwertiy - Да, пробовал и так и эдак. Всегда появляется окно: "Прекращена работа программы"

Answer (score 2):

Благодарю ответивших, действительно у библиотеки есть зависимости, пришлось поставить приложение на сторонний компьютер, и все заработало.

Решение плохое - поэтому буду искать другой вариант реализации функционала.

Ну по крайней мене хоть разобрался в чем была проблема.

Всем спасибо.

Comment: Да, если точнее - проблема в том, что вы используете interop - это не "настоящая" библиотека, а обертка поверх COM-компонента. Который надо отдельно ставить и регистрировать. Попробуйте найти чистую .net реализацию, без com/activex внутри.

Comment: ... или таки установить при инсталляции COM-компоненту. Или хотя бы положить COM dll в каталог и настроить SXS.